# Square brackets in Selenium Locators

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Just a bit curious to know if '[' has specific meaning while writing locators in selenium. Couldn't find anything on google.

ex.
Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']

Do they represent some kind of array of elements matching the criteria or does it have some specific meaning. 
for ex. in json arrays are enclosed in [], something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse the use of "[]" in Xpath with its use programming.

"[]" in programming means the index of the element

> but

In Xpath "[]" brackets can be used to specify index or conditions for selecting elements . In you an example: XPath ill select element "tagname" which contains attribute having a value equal to "value".

For more details on conditions please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Snippets

Comment: Agreed with both of you & thanks for the reply. Similar explanation is what is available on all the portal, but my curiosity is, why not to use  for e.g. Ex. //*button(text(),'OK')? It is just purely due to syntax or is there any logic around it...

Comment: and theny why specifying contains(text(),'keyword') why again we use contains() & enclose it in [contains(text(),'text')]?

Answer (score 1):

In Xpath we can use [ ] for -

1. Child Index :

> Ex. //tr[2] Means second tr child element on page.

2. condition on attributes :

> Ex. //*[@title='Ok'] . -> matches to any tag having attribute "title"
>   with value "Ok"

You can also use [ ] with Xpath axes methods.

> Ex. //*[text(),'OK']